# if C is closed in X, then C ∩ A is closed in A and C ∩ B is closed in B

Tags: general-topology

A, B, and C be subsets of a topological space X.

X = A ∪ B

Show that if C is closed in X, then C ∩ A is closed in A and C ∩ B is
closed in B.

would like to know a counterexample of the converse of the statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean with the respective subspace topologies. As $C^c$ is open in $X$, is also open in $A$ and $B$ by definition of subspace topology. Hence their complementaries are closed. For a counterexample take an open set $A\subseteq X$ which is not closed and write $X=A\cup A^c$, then $A\cap A$ and $A\cap A^c$ are closed in the respective topologies.

Comment: Provided that A is not closed in X.

Comment: That's true, sorry. I forgot because I was thinking in a nontrivial open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$.